# Storing comma separated .csv data from a web source into a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, web, store, live

I'm trying to download this comma separated info and save it so that it can be stored as a matrix which can then be accessed. So far I have code which I think should store the info in a file called test.csv but im not sure:

```
>> urlwrite('http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/JCMB_2013_Mar.csv','test.csv');

d = csvread('test.csv');



??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==> date-
Error in ==> csvread at 50
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
```

I am getting the above error. It reads the data fine using urlread. Does anybody know what the correct syntax should be and how I can get it stored as a matrix? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [readtext.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10946). That is a program which can read almost any text file. The problem in your data could be: they don't have uniform delimiters i.e. somewhere two columns are separated by `tab`, somewhere by `comma`.

The operation can be performed like this:

```
urlwrite('http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/JCMB_2013_Mar.csv','test.csv');
data= readtext('test.csv');
```

It should work.

Comment: How do I tabulate this function to include the URL for the file? It needs to be able to pull it directly from the site. If you could post an example that would make it clear. Apologies, I am very new to MATLAB/Coding in general.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

However I get:

??? Undefined function or method 'readtext' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Copy and pasted exactly as you typed.

Comment: Okay got it. Realised I needed to install my function. Thanks very much for your help!! How do I add to rep on here?/can I?

Comment: Because you have to download it from the link I gave and put it in the same directory which you can see if you go into the MATLAB command window.

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I add to rep on here?/can I?" What is "rep"

Comment: I wanted to add to your 'reputation' as a thanks for your help. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data directly from web without saving to file with URLREAD:

```
webdata = urlread('http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/JCMB_2013_Mar.csv');
```

This will give you the whole file as one string with lines delimited by '\n'. You can process it in multiple ways. For example:

```
tmp = textscan(webdata,['%s',repmat('%f',1,8)],'delimiter',',','headerlines',1);
date = tmp{1};
data = horzcat(tmp{2:end});
```

To get column headers you can do, for example:

```
colheader = textscan(webdata,'%s',1,'delimiter','\n'); 
colheader = regexp(colheader{:},',','split');
colheader = colheader{:};
```

You can also convert the data to a structure:

```
Data = cell2struct(tmp, genvarname(colheader),2);
```

Comment: Thank you!

My main objective is to use the data file in this link:

http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~weather/jcmb_ws/CR10X1.DAT

However, the data is very large and MATLAB is constantly 'Busy' and returns:

??? Error using ==> urlread at 111
Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down or your proxy settings
improperly configured.

Unsure how to get around it as its hosted on the same server. If there's no response for this then i'll post as a sep question. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean that urlwrite works but urlread does not? And "on the same server" you mean as the file in your example?

Comment: Neither work. Both produce the urlread at 111 error as stated above. The second file is much larger and will have therefore have far more matrix entries. Both files are hosted via the same site and I haven't had any security issues with the original file posted in this thread. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have problems downloading this large file with a standard browser? If no, may be you can think about the way to download the file outside of MATLAB. If you have to do it periodically you can setup a scheduling job. Then MATLAB can check the file existance, maybe check the timestamp, and do the processing. Also you can play with `Timeout` option in urlread/urlwrite. See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies right here:

```
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==> date-
```

Matlab says it encountered "date-" in the first cell. I guess you have a header row or two. You can check in the file and call

```
d = csvread('test.csv',ROW);
```

Where `ROW` is the number of the row where actual data starts (number of header rows + 1).